# Gremlin with low response time on 50M edge on AWS Neptune

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I am implementing a recommendation system with gremlin. I have 2M users and 20k books. When a user buys a book, it creates an edge to the book. I have total of 50M edge over the graph. I am using basic queries but it runs too slow. I am planing to give responses in the real time.

```
query = graph.V().hasLabel('user').hasId(user_id).match(
    _.as('u1').out().hasLabel('book').dedup().fold().as_('u1_books'),
    _.as('u1').V().hasLabel('user').as_('u2'),
    _.as('u2').out().hasLabel('book').dedup().fold().as_('u2_books')) \
    .where('u1', neq('u2')).as_('m') \
    .project('u1', 'u2', 'b1', 'b2') \
    .by(select('u1').id_()) \
    .by(select('u2').id_()) \
    .by(select('u1_books'').as_('n').select('m').select('u2_books'').unfold().where(within('n')).count()) \
    .by(union(select('u1_books''), select('u2_books'')).unfold().dedup().count()) \
    .project('u1', 'u2', 'int', 'un', 'similarity') \
    .by('u1') \
    .by('u2') \
    .by('b1') \
    .by('b2') \
    .by(__.math('b1/b2')).order().by('similarity', Order.desc).limit(LIMIT)
```

This is my query. I cannot find a way to expedite the response. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

```
    query = g.V().hasId(user).as_('u1').out().aggregate('u1_books').in_().where(neq('u1')).as_('u2')\
    .project('u1', 'u2', 'int', 'un') \
    .by(select('u1').id_()) \
    .by(select('u2').id_()) \
    .by(select('u1_books').as_('n').select('u2').out().where(within('n')).count()) \
    .by(union(select('u1_books'), select('u2').out()).unfold().dedup().count()).toList()
```

I considered your responses and make adjustments. The query that I'm trying to run is this now, even simpler. However, I cannot get a response. It gives a timeout error.

Comment: The query can be simplified quite a bit I think and also the `match` step can be replaced with some simpler steps that will allow the query planner to better optimize the query. If you are using Amazon Neptune sending the query to the `/gremlin/profile` end point will show you where the time is being spent but the `match` step is likely impacting query optimization.

Comment: Also at the very start it's not necessary to check a label if you are going to test for a specific ID.

Comment: What version of Neptune are you running?  You're using a `V()` in the middle of the query.  There was an optimization in 1.0.4.2 that greatly increased the performance of queries with a `V()` in the middle of the query.

Comment: I make adjustments according to your responses but I didn't gain much

Comment: So just breaking down this query a bit more, the output you're looking for is a list of results containing the original user (u1), the related user by common purchase (u2), a count of all common books the two users have purchased, and then a total count of all books purchased by both users?

Comment: yes. After this query, I will calculate jacquard similarly by calculating i/u.

Comment: Query performance should improve if you are able to provide labels to `in()` steps. This helps the query engine find the relevant edges faster.

Comment: I added labels but it still has over 2 minutes response time

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the query in a slightly different manner - performing as much of the traversal ahead of time prior to the project() statement.

As @Kelvin mentioned in the comments, unbounded in() steps in Neptune can be problematic as they do not bind to an index.  You really need to add whatever edge labels you have into the in() step to make that perform well.

Here's another version of the query:

```
g.V(user).as('u1').
    out('edge-label').as('u1_books').
    in('edge-label').where(neq('u1')).as('u2').
    select('u1','u2','u1_books').
        group().by(select('u1','u2')).unfold().
    project('u1','u2','int','un').
        by(select(keys).select('u1')).
        by(select(keys).select('u2')).
        by(select(values).unfold().dedup().count()).
        by(select(keys).select('u1','u2').select(values).
            unfold().in('edge-label').dedup().count())
```

To troubleshoot further, we would need to see an output of the Gremlin Profile API for this query to get a sense of how much data and what number of index operations are being performed:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-profile-api.html

Comment: memory limitation error with this query for my data set

Comment: this may be another topic, but are my expectations realistic for this data set ? is Neptune able to traverse this kind of data sets within seconds or even mseconds ?

Comment: Were you able to supply the edge labels within the in() steps?  In general, Neptune query performance will be based on the number of objects that need to be "touched" in the graph to compute the results.  Queries that only touch a few thousand objects will return in ms.  Queries that need to touch millions will take seconds.  This is regardless of overall graph size.  However, the data model should be built to help constrain the queries to only "touch" what is required to limit total query frontier.

Comment: I supplied the labels, in fact, there is only one type of edge that is going out from every vertex. But it still gets minute to execute the query I provided with labels and everything

Comment: And I think you query is not calculating anything.